# Is it possible to know if automated tools are used

Tags: jboss, webserver

Just wanted to know if it is possible to know from server that a webserver like Jboss is being accessd by a human being or by a automated tool from a remote system.

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge question that many people have been trying to solve for years, and the problem is not specific to JBoss.

If the automated tool is "good intentioned" it would usually provide a distinctive "User-Agent" header in its requests, by which one easily knows "who's asking". But if the automated tool is trying to pretend to be a human, things can get complicated. That's why CAPTCHA was invented, for example (see a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501514/how-to-detect-if-a-visitor-is-human-and-not-a-spider)).

Usually this type of question is considered "not constructive" here, so you'd need to be more specific about your situation.
Please also note that JBoss is more of an "application server" than "webserver".